# Use gcc 4.2 in Xcode 4.2 and iOS SDK 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gcc, compiler-construction

I just upgraded to Xcode 4.2 and iOS SDK 5 earlier today. But everything seems different with new compilers.

There are two "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" options now, "Apple LLVM compiler 3.0" and "LLVM GCC 4.2". GCC 4.2 is missing.

Apple LLVM compiler 3.0, builds really fast(I like that), gives me 999+ warnings, and my game can no longer run. It looks like there's some differences on memory, and it crashes when loading our game's scripts.

LLVM GCC 4.2 is so god damn slow, I still cannot finish one build after hours on my i7 machine.

And, one more thing is our engine uses gcc command lines to build(instead of xcode).

So, it leads to one question, **how can I use gcc 4.2 in Xcode 4.2**? Is that even possible?

Comment: I got the same issue, on XCode 4.2 Build 4D199, the /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 is not available, have you successfully installed it?

Comment: @dimas.priyanto Unfortunately not yet. However chown just provided an answer which looks great to me.

Comment: @dimas.priyanto I think I saw your answer about some GCC installer the other day, where is it now? I didn't noted the link...

Comment: Did anyone else receive the error "Error writing to -: Broken pipe". Has anyone successfully fixed this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to enable compiling with ***gcc 4.2*** in ***xcode 4.2***.  Most of this is done via command line so when you see lines like this: `[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$`, you need to open up a *Terminal* and run the command after the `$`.

> No files or directories are *removed* or *deleted* in this process, so it is easy to undo if you need to compile with LLVM in the future.

1. Download - but do **not** install *yet* - [xcode_4.1_for_lion.dmg](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_4.1_for_lion/xcode_4.1_for_lion.dmg) or [xcode_4.1_for_snow_leopard.dmg](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_4.1_for_snow_leopard_21110/xcode_4.1_for_snow_leopard.dmg)
2. Now, follow these steps to install Xcode 4.1 into `/Developer-4.1`:

   1. Backup the working `/Developer` directory (where Xcode 4.2 is installed)
     ```bsh
     [ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo mv -v /Developer /Developer-4.2
     ```
3. Run the Xcode 4.1 installer using the default install location (`/Developer`)
4. Move the new Xcode 4.1 installation to `/Developer-4.1`:

   ```bsh
   [ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo mv -v /Developer /Developer-4.1
   ```
5. Move the Xcode 4.2 developer directory back to `/Developer`:

   ```bsh
   [ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo mv -v /Developer-4.2 /Developer
   ```

Edit the Xcode 4.2 `GCC 4.2.xcspec` file to get gcc 4.2 to show in the list of compiler options <sup>[1]</sup>:

```bsh
[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo vi "/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/GCC 4.2 (Plausible Blocks).xcplugin/Contents/Resources/GCC 4.2.xcspec"
```

- Change lines **41** and **42** from this:

  ```bsh
  ShowInCompilerSelectionPopup = NO;
  IsNoLongerSupported = YES;
  ```
- To This:

  ```bsh
  ShowInCompilerSelectionPopup = YES; 
  IsNoLongerSupported = NO;
  ```

Backup the Xcode 4.2 iOS/Simulator Framework `usr` directories:

```bsh
[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo mv -v /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr.backup
[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo mv -v /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr.backup
```

Copy Xcode 4.1 iOS/Simulator Framework `usr` directories to Xcode 4.2:

```bsh
[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo cp -rv /Developer-4.1/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr
[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo cp -rv /Developer-4.1/usr /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr
```

Copy the `gcc` and `info` iOS SDK library directories from Xcode 4.1 to Xcode 4.2 <sup>[2]</sup>:

```bsh
[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo cp -rv /Developer-4.1/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/gcc /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/gcc
[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo cp -rv /Developer-4.1/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/info /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/info
```

**Compile using gcc-4.2!**

[image: Screenshot of CGG 4.2 in xcode 4.2]

---

**[This is a blog post I've written with a little more info about this process.  Feel free to leave a comment on the blog if you run into any issues or have any questions.](http://blog.hozbox.com/2011/11/08/how-to-use-gcc-4-2-with-xcode-4-2/)**

---

<sup>[1]</sup> If opening from a command line (using something like `vi`, `emacs`, `nano`, etc) make sure to either enclose the path in quotes <kbd>"/long path/with spaces/in it/file.xcspec"</kbd> or escape the spaces <kbd>/some/long\ path/with\ spaces/in\ it/file.xcspec</kbd>

<sup>[2]</sup> This is necessary because the iPhoneOS.platform SDK has its own seperate `/usr/lib` directories but the iPhoneSimulator.platform SDK does not

Comment: WoW, looks like going to work. Thank you. I'll try it on monday

Comment: Did you personally found it out of no where? I can hardly image how much you know about the Xcode IDE

Comment: @ZhaoXiang I figured this out over about 3 days of trial and error.  It was very frustrating, but I finally got it to build and run on the simulator and on my actual iOS 5.0 device!

Comment: Does this solution supports new features in iOS 5 like Auto Reference Counting or iCloud?

Comment: Only clang supports ARC. iCloud should work, as it's just a matter of API support.

Comment: I did not tried it yet, I'll do it as soon as I can, but I like this answer, so I decide to accept it now. Thank you.

Comment: anyone had success with this? I tried it and failed, xcode won't start up. I had to roll back to xcode4.02 (xcode 4.1 provided via link takes too long to load the installation window as well) Now I think back, it may be due to the fact xcode icon was linked to 4.1 instance rather than 4.2, but not sure.

Comment: @Eugene - I've tested this a ton (using clean installs of 4.2 and 4.1) and it does work.  It sounds to me like theres something else that is wrong b/c even if you mess up the commands above, you would only get errors during a build/compile.  There's nothing that this process does that could possibly prevent Xcode from running.  Did you get any error popup dialogs when you tried to run xcode?

Comment: @chown: No it didn't give any error popup, maybe something was messed up with the xcode link, I'll try it again soon. Thanks

Comment: Did anyone else receive the error "Error writing to -: Broken pipe". Has anyone successfully fixed this ?

Answer (score 3):

In this years WWDC, Apple stated that GCC is no longer available in XCode 4.2. However, they stated that the LLVM compiler supports the same command line switches as GCC.

Comment: My Mac has a i7 CPU with four cores, 6GM RAM, LLVM can only compile 8 files, before they run out my CPU and memory. I guess I'll roll back to iOS SDK 4.2, and wait for the game engine provider update their engine.

Comment: GCC is indeed deprecated, but it is still available at /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 after installing Xcode 4.2, but I can't find a way to have Xcode using it. The compiler setting in my target allows for a "Other..." choice, but nothing seems to work there.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to update this for the applified version of Xcode. This will show how to install Xcode 4.4.x with full gcc support.

You need: Mac OSX Lion - this is important, don't try with Mountain Lion!

You need: a copy of Xcode 4.1 for Lion. Download from Apple with your dev account. Don't install yet.

Now install Xcode 4.4.x from Apple via Mac App Store.

After this is done, you will have xcode 4.4.x in your applications directory.

Depending on user rights, you will have to confirm many of the actions with your admin password. Just do so when necessary. If you damage your system, you are on your own (that should not happen though, as Xcode has been applified).

Open Xcode 4.4.x via right mouse click and "Show Package Contents" and then navigate to the gcc 4.2 plugin here:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/GCC 4.2.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/

Open the file gcc 4.2.xcspec with a text editor.

Look at lines 41and 42. Make sure they look exactly as presented here (the values will be reversed in a fresh install).

```
ShowInCompilerSelectionPopup = YES;
IsNoLongerSupported = NO;
```

Save and close.

Install Xcode 4.1 for Lion.

Now navigate to the developer directory at the root of your boot drive.

Navigate to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/

copy the usr directory with command-c

switch back to xcode 4.4.x

navigate to: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/

paste the usr directory with command-v

now lion will try to merge the two directories. Make sure to press "Keep Newer"

Repeat with source: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr
And target: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/usr

Again, merge and "Keep Newer"

Navigate to: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib

Now copy the gcc directory by selecting it and using command-c

Navigate into the Xcode 4.4.x app:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/lib

Paste the gcc directory with command-v

Repeat from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib with 'info' directory
target is again /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/lib

Done. Launch xcode and chose GCC 4.2 in settings where necessary. You should delete the outdated "Developer" directory.

Xcode should now also accept updates via Mac App Store again (this remains to be tested). I also did not download command line tools, but my guess is it will survive that too.

Comment: I had success with xcode 4.5 as well for device. but fails miserably for simulators.. xcode warns 'class uiimageview is unavailable', 'UIBackgroundTaskInvalid' is unavailable and so forth