# The last Xcode 4.2.1 doesn't install all devtools packages

Tags: xcode, installation, devtools

I have a big problem,
My macintosh HD was dead. So I formated all my datas. Great ! :(

I downloaded and installed xcode with the Mac AppStore but I have several errors.
Apparently, the all devtools aren't installed.

Doxygen is not installed, GCC4.2 is not installed, ...

Is there a devtools package ?

Best.

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen I've never heard of, so I don't think it's included with Apple's standard dev tools package.  You can probably find an installable [download by Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=doxygen+download).

GCC is a different thing.  It no longer ships with XCode development tools.  Apple would prefer you move to [LLVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Level_Virtual_Machine) or whatever their latest compiler is. If you really want GCC 4.2, [there may be some ways to get it](http://ask.metafilter.com/200231/How-to-install-gcc-42-on-a-macbook-with-Xcode-42). Oh, I just found a duplicate question about GCC ( [Use gcc 4.2 in Xcode 4.2 and iOS SDK 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765157/use-gcc-4-2-in-xcode-4-2-and-ios-sdk-5-0) ).

Oh, and to be prepared for (the hopefully not likely) next time your machine dies, I'd definitely recommend setting up a second detachable hard drive and [Time Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_%28Mac_OS%29).