# Using GCC 4.2 in Xcode 4.2 iOS SDK 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gcc, compiler-construction

I found this post about using GCC 4.2 in Xcode 4.2 [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765157/use-gcc-4-2-in-xcode-4-2-and-ios-sdk-5-0).
Did anyone else receive the error "Error writing -: Broken pipe" after following the steps in the above post?

After following the steps I can see GCC 4.2 as an option for the compiler.
Compiling a project using LLVM compiler 3.0 still works, but using LLVM GCC 4.2 or GCC 4.2 generates the pipe error.

I hope someone encountered the same problem and managed to fix it!

Comment: Reboot your Mac and iPhone. It usually fixes the error.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't fix the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and userful solution https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/
It automates the lists of the declaration on the stackoverflow